# EMAIL [WinError 10060]

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I had a program in PYTHON that sends e-mail through the GMAIL server, about six months ago due to the worsening of GMAIL's security, the application was blocked, and I changed the e-mail account to two-step verification, and added a password to the application, last week they changed the IP addresses of the computer running the application, and the e-mail was blocked with an error message "[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond properly after a period of time, or the connection establishment failed because the connected host failed to respond"
I created a new email password for the app, and still the same error.
Thank you very much to anyone who can help

my email code:

```
enter code here

@retry(stop_max_delay=60000)
def mail(gmail_user, gmail_pwd, to, subject, text, attach=None):
    to = to if 'list' in str(type(to)) else [to]

    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = gmail_user
    msg['To'] = to[0]
    msg['Cc'] = ','.join(to[1:])
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

    if attach:
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
        encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                        'attachment', filename=('utf-8', 'he', os.path.basename(attach)))
        msg.attach(part)

    # mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    # mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
    mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())
    # Should be mailServer.quit(), but that crashes...
    mailServer.close()
enter code here
```

Comment: I see you commented out the one with port 587. Could it be any of these ports: 25, 587, 465, or 2525? But I think the actual reason is that SSL needs a certificate provided with the kwargs `keyfile=NotNone, certfile=NotNone`

Comment: check the constructor for [smtplib.SMTP_SSL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL)

Comment: From my local computer it still works without changing the code, and on the remote computer I changed to SMTP without SSL (following your response) and it still doesn't work. and I also add ssl.create_default_context() to the SMTP function, and i get the same error